# In OSX, is there a way for an app to access the iTunes library without targeting individual audio files in Finder?

Tags: macos, itunes

I am making an OSX app that needs to access the user's iTunes library. Is there a way to do this without going through the file system and reading the .m4a files individually?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is a scriptable application ie one that can be controlled by AppleScript scripts. For examples see [Doug's of Applescripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/)

This control can also be done via the S[cripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html) from objective C

Answer (score 1):

In ~/Music/iTunes/, there's a file called "iTunes Music Library.xml", which is a plain ol' XML file that has all the information about everything in your iTunes library.